# Warning modal and session timeout

Tags: reactjs

I have a requirement to display warning pop up for 28minutes and auto logout for 30 minutes, so if i click ok on that pop up it should trigger to 30minutes more. I need to achieve this using react.js. If anyone knows a way to do this, please share with me.

Answer (score 0):

I have added to the code sandbox here an implementation of what you are describing. Instead of doing 30 minutes, I have used 3 minutes and I logout at the last second of the three minutes. you can modify these figures to your taste. [sample code here](https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-hooks-zu9fe?file=/src/App.js)